# Create symlink to file that doesn't exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink

I'm writing a script in python.

I want to create a symlink to a file that doesn't exist.

os.symlink fails in this case.

Is there a way to force to link?

Comment: What OS are you on? `os.symlink` seems to be able to do this on MacOS and Linux. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762831/create-broken-symlink-with-python

Comment: As a little workaround: just create a new empty file at the destination, create the symlink and delete the file?